# How to save table1 package output table to .doc format? R

Tags: r, datatables

Package "table1" allows for some amazing tables to be made. However, i can't figure how to export one to .doc format.

Here is an example code:

`table1( ~ x | Y, data = df)`

I wonder if it is possible to somehow save resulting table into .doc format so it still looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out it's very simple:

Just cmd+a the table in Rstudio viewer -> cmd+c -> paste Special in MS Word -> chose .html format!

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry to dig this up. However I learnt to love the two packages `table1` and aswell `flextable` and  one other route would be to fastly convert the table1 object to a flextable

```
library(table1)
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)

# Create Table1 Object
tbl1<- table1(~Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width|Species,data=iris)
# Convert to flextable
t1flex(tbl1) %>% 
  save_as_docx(path="Iris_table1.docx")
```

Note that this give you the full flexibility over working with a flextable and an easy and save way to export to word. A nice guide on additional formatting with flextable can be found [here](https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:
The above strategy did not work for me when I had a similar issue, but it was resolved once I knitted the table1 object and opened the html **in browser** to copy the html table and successfully paste into word. Doing it within RStudio viewer would not work for me for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can also save it as a .csv file for further manipulation (and from there to word)

```r
mytable <- table1( ~ x | Y, data = df)

write.table (mytable , "my_table_1_file.csv", col.names = T, row.names=F, append= T, sep=',')
```

Comment: That seems to produce an HTML file?